Standalone single binary database for time series data
I am looking for a database that ticks the following boxes:

Single binary, or portable version that can be executed without installation, available for Windows and Linux
Library for at least Python to connect to the DB and insert and query data from multiple processes
In-memory or persistent
Open Source

Usage scenario is for time-series data with continuous insertion of small blobs (acquisition of metrics) and regular query of larger amounts (plotting, live analysis) from different threads that run locally on commodity hardware.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Systems (and tools, libraries...) recommendations are not OT (on-topic) as either "shopping-list" or "opinion-based" questions. Perhaps better asked on software-recs? But if I were looking at a db for this, look at Firebird Embedded server or SQLite. SQLite can have multiple readers but only one writer, whereas Firebird can (AIUI) support simultaneous writes.
